# webpack error in missing path @ multi main

Tags: build, reactjs, webpack

I'm seeing an error in webpack when I try to run my build.

```
webpack --config conf/webpack.build.config.js --progress --colors --display-error-details --display-modules --display-reasons
Hash: e633ac8cf3ba9196f876
Version: webpack 1.12.9
Time: 312ms
                     Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
tinymce-comments-plus-bundle.js  5.88 kB       0  [emitted]  main
  [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
  [1] ./js/tinymce-comments-plus.js 0 bytes [built] [failed]
      single entry ./js/tinymce-comments-plus.js [0] multi main
ERROR in missing path
@ multi main
```

Options.build is true when the npm task is running. I've tried adjusting the paths but can't seem to find which path is wrong. Where is @ multi main?

Here is my webpack config.

```
module.exports = function( options ) {

var path = require( 'path' ),
    cssLoaders = 'style!css',
    scssLoaders = cssLoaders + '!sass',
    babelLoader = 'react-hot!babel',
    webpack = require( 'webpack' ),
    ExtractTextPlugin = require( 'extract-text-webpack-plugin' );

function extractLoaders( extract, loaders ) {
  return ExtractTextPlugin.extract( extract, loaders.substr( loaders.indexOf( '!' ) ) );
}

if ( options.build ) {
    cssLoaders = extractLoaders( 'style', cssLoaders );
    scssLoaders = extractLoaders( 'style', scssLoaders );
    babelLoader = extractLoaders( 'react-hot', babelLoader );
}


return {
    entry: [ './js/tinymce-comments-plus.js' ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/../js',
        publicPath: options.build ? '/dist/' : 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: 'tinymce-comments-plus-bundle.js',
        // hot: true,
        // headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: cssLoaders
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: scssLoaders
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: babelLoader
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: babelLoader
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        root: [
            path.join( __dirname, '..', 'components' ),
            path.join( __dirname, '..', 'js' ),
            path.join( __dirname, '..', 'sass' ),
        ],
        extensions: [ '', '.js', '.jsx', '.sass', '.scss', '.css' ],
    },
    plugins: options.build ? [
        // build plugins
        new ExtractTextPlugin( './css/[name].css' ),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                warnings: false
            }
        }),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ] : [
        // dev plugins
        new ExtractTextPlugin( './css/[name].css' ),
        //new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
}; }
```

Comment: Can you provide your app file structure ? What is the extension of `tinymce-comments-plus` ? `.js` or `.jsx` ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The tinymce-comments-plus.js extension is .js. For the app file structure, npm runs the scripts off of /package.json in the root. /js/ holds the javascript and /conf/ holds the webpack config js. /node_modules/ holds all the npm dependencies. /components/ has sub directories with .jsx react components.

Comment: Did you find any work-arounds?

Comment: I ended up solving this by installing some NPM packages. In my particular case, I believe it was the babel-loader...but I think this error can show for a number of reasons.

Comment: I wasn't able to resolve this issue. I ended up moving my project to a newer scaffold (newtriks react-webpack) which solved all my webpack issues.

Comment: Are you running this on windows machine?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I would recommend installing webpack globally using `npm install -g webpack` then linking to the global installation `npm link webpack`

Also, ensure that you have your extension linked to `resolve.extensions`

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.tsx', '.js'] // <-- Had to add the .js one
}
```